# How to write urls in static format in django

Tags: python, django

I am unable to upload

```
style="background-image:url(images/home_slider.jpg)"
```

file in django. I have made two changes in settings .That is as follows:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=[ os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')]
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')
```

I also tried this

```
style=" {% static'background-image:url(images/home_slider.jpg)' %}"
```

But unable to remove error.

Comment: Does your static files work properly in other static places except `background-image`

Comment: yes it works well where there is no urls.

Answer (score 0):

Add static only where you use the path of the file. So:

```
style="background-image: url({% static 'images/home_slider.jpg' %});"
```

Don't forget to place `{% load static %}` at the top.

Comment: <div class="owl-item">
<div class="background_image" style="backgroundimage:url(images/home_slider.jpg)"></div>
<div class="home_slider_content_container">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
         <div class="home_slider_content">
          <div class="home_title"><h2>Let us take you away</h2></div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

Adding more details:

load static files in your template

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Usage of img tag:
`<img src="{% static 'images/image.jpg'%}" alt="">`

In your case:
`style="background-image: url('{% static "images/image.jpg" %}');"`